# Overflow auto not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to create a user dashboard with top and side navbars. The problem faced by me is that `overflow: auto` is not working properly. I get scroll bar but it does not scroll till the end of the page.

My fiddle link - [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/nayyarmannu/bzbmLw47/2/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=bzbmLw47)

In mobile devices there is no problem but I am facing this problem in full width devices (laptop).

Along with that, how can we center the font awesome icon and the links in the sidebar like this?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: check my updated jsfiddle please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bzbmLw47/7/) You can add some `padding` in the bottom so your content will be all visible in the window.

Also i have updated the jsfiddle and added some more styling so the icons now are centered.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO

Change `<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-11 affix-content" style="overflow-y:scroll;">` with `<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-11 affix-content">` you don't need `overflow-y` there, and change body `overflow` to `overflow-x:hidden` instead of `overflow:hidden` and `height:auto` instead of `height:100%`

and it works

see the [jsFiddle Updated](https://jsfiddle.net/MoolsBytheway/bzbmLw47/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the correct way to fix it but it seamed to work fine when I changed this in you CSS:

```
 .affix-row,
 .affix-container,
 .affix-content {
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
 }
```

To this

```
 .affix-row,
 .affix-container,
 .affix-content {
    height: 90%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
 }
```

Hope it helps at the very least i've narrowed it down to :

```
height: 100%;
```

To fix your icon center problem you could remove pixels from the top of each icon like this:

```
.fa-cloud-download:before {
  margin-top:-10px;
 }
```